# Resize multiple items inside of a WxPython BoxSizer evenly?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm attempting to stack multiple widgets in a Horizontal `BoxSizer`. However, I'm getting a bit of unexpected behavior. Rather than the items in the Sizer resizing evenly, once a certain size is reached, the items will stop resizing along with the window.

This is best understood visually, I think. So, in gif form:

**Current Behavior:**

[image]

If you'll notice, the two `TextCtrl`s resize in step with each other until about the half-way mark, at which point they both stop resizing and instead get "pushed" underneath the window.

**Desired Behavior:**

[image]

The desired Behavior is that, even at the smallest size, the two `TextCtrl`would still be split evenly (The above was achieved via photoshop)

For just the two widgets shown, it's not really a huge issue, as the window can be resized smaller than any user ever would before the uneven `TextCtrl` issue ever pops up. However! In the actual application, I need to have anywhere from 3-5 of these (made of of various widget types) stacked next to each other. While two isn't an issue, adding more (especially when space and padding is added) quickly makes the problem more apparent.

[image]

**Full Code:**

```
import wx
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel


class TestPanel(ScrolledPanel):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False)

    self.textctrls = [wx.TextCtrl(self) for _ in range(4)]

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    for textctrl in self.textctrls:
      hsizer.Add(textctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)

    sizer.Add(hsizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="test", size=(320, 240))
    self.SetBackgroundColour('#ffffff')
    self.panel = TestPanel(self)
    self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = wx.App(False)
  MyFrame(None)
  app.MainLoop()
```

The code should be relatively straight forward. All the heavy listing is done in the `ScrolledPanel` subclass. I create the buttons, add each one to a Horizontal `BoxSizer`, and finally add the Horizontal sizer into a vertical container.

Could anyone identify why the widgets in the sizer are not resizing correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the textctrls minsize to zero so they can go smaller then their default minsize.

```
import wx
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel


class TestPanel(ScrolledPanel):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False)

    self.textctrls = [wx.TextCtrl(self) for _ in range(4)]

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    for textctrl in self.textctrls:
      hsizer.Add(textctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
      textctrl.SetMinSize((0, -1))

    sizer.Add(hsizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="test", size=(320, 240))
    self.SetBackgroundColour('#ffffff')
    self.panel = TestPanel(self)
    self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = wx.App(False)
  MyFrame(None)
  app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This provides the solution but not the explanation, which is that the layout algorithm tries to preserve the min size as much as possible. If there is not enough space to satisfy min sizes of all items, it will try to satisfy min size constraint for as many of them as possible, which explains what you see with the original code.